# Clojure - boot compose task

Tags: clojure, build, tooling

I am using [`boot`](https://github.com/boot-clj/boot), and I am happy with it so far.
I still have to run two tasks currently, in two different consoles :
`boot dev` and `boot autotest`.

Therefore I would like to know it it is feasible/advised to make all boot tasks within the same JVM.

I tried to compose the tasks like so :

```
(deftask autotest []
  (comp
    (watch)
    (run-tests)))

(deftask dev
  "Start the dev env..."
  [t run-tests       bool "Run the tests continuously"]
  (comp
   ....
   (if run-tests (autotest) identity)))
```

But now when running `boot dev -t` I get an exception from one of the libraries that I am using, which could mean that I have to isolate it.

Are boot tasks intended to be used like that, and can boot `pods` solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

- I no longer have this exception
- this is one of the strength of `boot` to use one single JVM (as opposed to leiningen)